# Cast icon missing in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I'm migrating my project from Cast Companion Library to Cast v3. To do so I've updated my dependencies to the latest available, and also updated my system images. Now if I try to test my project on an emulator no cast icon is being shown. If I test on my real device everything is ok. Before the cast icon was appearing in the emulators. Is there a change in the new sdk that prevents testing on emulators or the problem is somewhere else? I've also checked the YouTube app from the emulator and its the same - no cast icon is ever shown.

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs for the emulator?

Comment: There are some internal errors in the log but I can't isolate an error that is shared between all emulators. I've created an emulator with API 22 and strangely the cast functionality works well with it. So far I've noticed the problem with missing discovery on emulators running API 25 and API 26.

Comment: You can file an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc

Answer (score 1):

API23 is the last API that works with with casting in the emulator.  If you need to debug Google cast, create something like a Next 6p with API23 and you should be OK.  It won't show Wifi networks, but it will enumerate cast devices.